# Reading GTFS-realtime with java : including an existing package

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I want to read protobuffer GTFS-realtime inputs using java, and this package
https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings/blob/master/java/README.md

I created first a java project using Maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.me.app -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
cd myproject
mvn package
```

...went fine.
According to the documentation of the GTFS-realtime binding package, the following should be included in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.transit</groupId>
  <artifactId>gtfs-realtime-bindings</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

In order to avoid duplicates (which made the compilation crashed) I removed the following lines:

```
<groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
```

so I got this pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.me.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.transit</groupId>
  <artifactId>gtfs-realtime-bindings</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The compilation then crashed. I am a newcomer in java and may have missed a point about how to include an existing package into a new project. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Give this a shot: https://github.com/laidig/nyct-gtfs-rt-example . You'll need to replace the URL in the Main class with your own, but it should be pretty quick

Comment: I didn't have a problem with your POM. Are you using maven from the command line, IntelliJ, or Eclipse?

Comment: I will give a try with your two suggestions, starting with a wiped-clean dir, and come back to say how it worked